# How do I call C functions from Java code on Linux

Tags: c, gcc, java-native-interface, java

I am writing a Java program on Suse Linux 11 using JavaSE-1.6 and I am having a problem building using javac.

I am following the tutorial on

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

and have so far written the following:

```
package com.ctest;

class CTest
{
    // Native method declaration
    native int testCall();

    // Load the library
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("fpdpReaderLib");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int retVal;

        // Create class instance
        CTest cLangTest = new CTest();

        // Call native method
        retVal = cLangTest.testCall();

        System.out.println(retVal);
    }
}
```

When I run javac CTest.java i get an error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.3/../../../crt1.o: in function '_start':
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.9/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:115: undefined reference to 'main'
/tmp/cc97kcJu.o:(.data+0x28) undefined reference to 'hidden alias for int com::ctest::CTest::testCall()'
/tmp/cc97kcJu.o:(.data+0x74) undefined reference to 'hidden alias for int com::ctest::CTest::testCall()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am suspecting it is using gcc rather than the java version of javac but I'm not sure.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

I have tried using the "--main=" option mentioned here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/java/faq.html#4_1

but instead of the error before I now just get:

```
/tmp/ccwfugWq.o:(.data+0x28) undefined reference to 'hidden alias for int com::ctest::CTest::testCall()'
/tmp/ccwfugWq.o:(.data+0x74) undefined reference to 'hidden alias for int com::ctest::CTest::testCall()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should install and use the Sun Java SDK rather than using the gcc javac compiler.

Google for [suse javac gcc](http://www.google.com/search?q=suse%20javac%20gcc) throws up loads of similar problems and the solution always seems to be to use the Sun JDK.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my JDK had been messed up and now I have re-installed it, the paths have been fixed and I can run javac with no problems and javah has now created my header file correctly.

Answer (score 2):

From the page that you cited:

> The library containing the native code implementation is loaded by a
>   call to System.loadLibrary(). Placing this call in a static
>   initializer ensures this library is only loaded once per class. The
>   library can be loaded outside of the static block if your application
>   requires it. **You might need to configure your environment so the
>   loadLibrary method can find your native code library.**

My emphasis. Have you set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or whatever is appropriate) for your system?

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my JDK had been messed up and now I have re-installed it, the paths have been fixed and I can run javac with no problems and javah has now created my header file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you run `which javac` to determine which compiler you are using.  If you want Java 6, you can't use gcj.  You need to fix you PATH so you have using a `javac` from JDK 6.